# pydantic v2.0.0 with pylint no-member warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pylint, pydantic

### Questuion

- in [pydantic doc](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields),pydantic ^2.0.0 not support like this `a:Optional[str]`,but rather support `a:Optional[str] = Field(default=None)`
- however,pylint check my code raise warning`[E1101(no-member), get] Instance of 'FieldInfo' has no 'split' member`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional


class A(BaseModel):
    a: Optional[str] = Field(default=None)


def get(**kwargs):
    return A(**kwargs).a.split(" ")
```

### Attempt

- if i use `a:Optional[str] = None` can solve all the problems above,but my project some fileds use Field
- Declare pylint disable check in pyfile: `pylint: disable=no-member`
- Declare pylint disable check in .pylinrc

How can I solve the above problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Annotated` to decorate your fields using pydantic's `Field`. Something like this should work for you:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Annotated, Optional


class A(BaseModel):
    a: Annotated[Optional[str], Field(default=None)]


def get(**kwargs):
    return A(**kwargs).a.split(" ")
```

The reason why it's failing is due to how pylint analyses static attributions like this, using `Field`'s result as the value instead of the type hints we've provided.

This should work for other `Field` attributes as well:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Annotated, Any, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Kind(Enum):
    ABC = "abc"


class MyClass(BaseModel):
    kind: Annotated[Optional[Kind], Field(default=None, alias="Kind")]


args: dict[str, Any] = {"Kind": "abc"}

obj = MyClass(**args)

print(obj.kind)  # Kind.ABC
```